# How to Sign-out of Facebook Authentication in Firebase SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am using the firebase SDK in my iOS project. I create an anonymous account just after the app launch.

For facebook login, I use the following code -

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential)
```

How should I implement sign-out? I need the user to get back to the firebase anonymous account.

Should I directly call firebase signout and create a new anonymous account?

```
try! Auth.auth().signOut()

Auth.auth().signInAnonymously()
```

or should I call logout method of FBSDKLoginManager, will this persist the firebase anonymous user, which was there before facebook login?

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

or should I unlink the provider?

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.unlink(fromProvider: providerID!)
```

What should be the ideal way here?

Comment: I wrote a quick answer below of how to think of the authentication states. But I don't fully understand your use-case, as it feels a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I want to know how to go back to anonymous account after signout?

Comment: Can I retain the same uid in anonymouse account  after signout from facebook?

Comment: As I answered below, that depends on how you handle the sign-in with Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sign a user in to Firebase Authentication through Facebook, they need to be signed in with Facebook, and with Firebase Authentication. If you want to then sign that user into Firebase Authentication with another provider, you only need to sign them out of Firebase Authentication.

---

Linking and unlinking providers serves another use-case. Say that you want to allow the user to sign in with their Google account, in addition to the Facebook account they're now signed in with.

In that case you can leave the user signed in, create separate authentication credentials for their Google account, and [link the two providers together](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking). From that moment on, no matter if the user signs in with their Facebook or with their Google credentials, they will be signed in to the same Firebase Authentication account.

Calling `unlink` after that allows you to unlink one of the providers from the account.

---

**Update** I think I understand now...

1. You had a user that was signed in anonymously.
2. Then you signed them in with a Facebook account.
3. And next you signed them out of their Facebook account.
4. Now you want to go back to the previous anonymous authentication account.

This is not possible. When you sign the user into Facebook, they are signed out of their previous account. And when a user is signed out of anonymous authentication, that account cannot be recovered.

If this *is* a normal use-case for your app, you'll have to **link** the Facebook account to the existing anonymous authentication account in step 2 above (instead of replacing it). If you do that, you can indeed unlink the Facebook account and get back to (only) the anonymous authentication provider.